# UIWebView Act Different For The Same URL Compared To Safari/Chrome

Tags: javascript, ios, safari, uiwebview

I'm getting this very strange behavior.

I'm loading the same URL from my iPhone browser(Safari), and from a UIWebView from my project. So far so good.

For some reason, I have this button over the website **appearing both at the UIWebView,and at the browser**

[image]

which trigger this(**ONLY at the BROWSER,at the UIWebView it doesn't trigger anythings** :

[image]

**Any Suggestions?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved.

I investigated a bit and found out there is `WKWebView` which fully supports JavaScript.

**Update**

```
import UIKit
import WebKit
import JavaScriptCore


class Sample: UIViewController {
    var webView: WKWebView?


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let url = NSURL (string: "http://www.google.com");
        /* Create our preferences on how the web page should be loaded */
        let preferences = WKPreferences()
        preferences.javaScriptEnabled = true

        /* Create a configuration for our preferences */
        let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        configuration.preferences = preferences
        /* Now instantiate the web view */
        webView = WKWebView(frame: self.view!.bounds, configuration: configuration)

        if let theWebView = webView{
            /* Load a web page into our web view */
            let urlRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
            theWebView.loadRequest(urlRequest)
            view.addSubview(theWebView)
        }


    }



}
```